# How to download data from beeline hive in csv2 format?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, beeline

I'm having issue while downloading data from hive via beeline.

I want to download a table into file with csv as field delimiter. If the column value has comma, then that value needs to be enclosed by quote.

I know that beeline provides outputformat csv2 for this use case.

But I'm not getting the expected results out.

I've created sample table with data for this purpose.

```
    0: jdbc:hive2://ip:10000/default> DESC samp_ret;
+-------------+------------+----------+--+
|  col_name   | data_type  | comment  |
+-------------+------------+----------+--+
| intvar      | int        |          |
| stringvar1  | string     |          |
| stringvar2  | string     |          |
+-------------+------------+----------+--+
3 rows selected (0.081 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://ip:10000/default>  SELECT * FROM samp_ret ;
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--+
| samp_ret.intvar  | samp_ret.stringvar1  | samp_ret.stringvar2  |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--+
| 1                | one,ONE              | One                  |
| 2                | 2                    | Two                  |
| 3                |                      | Three                |
| 4                | four,FOUR            |                      |
| 5                | five'FIVE            | Five                 |
| 6                | six',SIX             | Six                  |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--+
6 rows selected (0.164 seconds)
```

I'm trying to download this data into app server, but for some reason, I'm not seeing the records containing comma enclosed in quote.

Beeline command used is ,

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://ip:10000/default?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round -n yumecorp yumehive org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --silent -e "SELECT * FROM dev.samp_ret " > /tmp/samp_ret.out
```

Output is ,

[image]

As you can see in the output, If the column value has comma, then the it's displayed as ^@

Let me know if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Export** the below property in the shell before executing your beeline command

```
bash$ export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Ddisable.quoting.for.sv=false"
```

Then execute the beeline export command

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://ip:10000/default?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round -n yumecorp yumehive org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --silent -e "SELECT * FROM dev.samp_ret " > /tmp/samp_ret.out
```

**Example:**

I have 2 string columns in a tables after

```
hive> select * from i;
+-------+---------+--+
| i.id  | i.name  |
+-------+---------+--+
| 1     | kl,kl   |
| 2     | ll,mm   |
+-------+---------+--+
```

Now exporting to csv file with enclosed "" for **name column values**

```
bash$ export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Ddisable.quoting.for.sv=false"
bash$ beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --silent -e "SELECT * FROM default.i" > samp_ret.out
bash$ cat samp_ret.out 
1,"kl,kl"
2,"ll,mm"
```

Refer to this [hive Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14679) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I initially tried it along the beeline command which didn't seem to work. It makes sense now.